# Deferred with jQuery - when() with getJSON() callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I'm trying to understand `when` function and deferred objects in jQuery.

```
$.when($.getJSON('/echo/json', function () {
    console.log('sucess');
}, function () {
    console.log('error');
})).then(console.log('get JSON ready!'));
```

This example returns:

```
get JSON ready!
sucess
```

...but I want to achieve that success callback fires first:

```
sucess
get JSON ready!
```

How can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/lukaszr/rBFmL/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot the function wrapper - your code calls `console.log` immediately instead of passing a callback function:

```
.then(console.log('get JSON ready!'));
```

Should be:

```
.then(function() {
    console.log('get JSON ready!');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rBFmL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using .done(...) instead of .then(...). There are examples right in the jQuery documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/